# dbms_metadata bug if I try to generate ddl for java?

Tags: oracle11g, metadata

I have to copy some objects from one schema to another on the same database, between others java sources too. The dbms_metadata.get_ddl(object_type, object_name, schema_name) returns schema name in the ddl. Because I want to execute this ddl on the new schema the old schema name in the ddl doesn't help me in my job. To avoid this problem I use a following function a step before:

execute dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform,'EMIT_SCHEMA', false);

In case of a table it works (it means, it omits the schema name in ddl):

select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', object_name, schema_name) from dual;

but in case of java source:

select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('JAVA_SOURCE', object_name, schema_name) from dual;

it doesn't!

I've tested these functions on VM with database 12.2 from Oracle too. The same behavior.

Is it a bug? Any workaround?

Regards,
Jacek